# MySql Error 1103

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Good Morning,

I'm using MySql Workbench to create some databases of mine and i haven't had problems since this monday.

Whem i'm "Forward Engeneer"ing my model, all tables are created without problems, except this guy here:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1103: Incorrect table name '1'

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sigemV2`.`macro` (
  `MACRO_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `MACRO_ADDRESS` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `MACRO_DESCRIPTION` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `MACRO_MACRO_KIND_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MACRO_ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_MACRO_MACRO_KIND1_idx` (`MACRO_MACRO_KIND_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `MACRO_KIND_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`MACRO_MACRO_KIND_ID` )
    REFERENCES `sigemV2`.`macrokind` (`MACRO_KIND_ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
INDEX DIRECTORY = '1'
```

I'm pretty used to MySql workbench, but this is drivin me crazy :(.

I tryed also on phpMyAdmin, but i had the same error (1103), but the difference was that phpMyAdmin pointed the problem to the "**primary Key ('MACRO_ID')**" line.

I appreciate your help in advance!

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INDEX DIRECTORY = '1'` Index directory must refer to valid directory.

Comment: Thank you Hamlet, for the fast answer to my question!
I removed the "index directory" option from the .sql file and the database was generated.

I hope this don't bring more problems :).

Thank you once again! _O_

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the INDEX DIRECTORY option. That has to point to a file.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html for a complete syntax manual of create table.

The chapter about INDEX DIRECTORY from that page:

> By using DATA DIRECTORY='directory' or INDEX DIRECTORY='directory' you can specify where the MyISAM storage engine should put a table's data file and index file. The directory must be the full path name to the directory, not a relative path.
>
> These options work only when you are not using the --skip-symbolic-links option. Your operating system must also have a working, thread-safe realpath() call. See Section 8.11.3.1.2, “Using Symbolic Links for MyISAM Tables on Unix”, for more complete information.
>
> If a MyISAM table is created with no DATA DIRECTORY option, the .MYD file is created in the database directory. By default, if MyISAM finds an existing .MYD file in this case, it overwrites it. The same applies to .MYI files for tables created with no INDEX DIRECTORY option. To suppress this behavior, start the server with the --keep_files_on_create option, in which case MyISAM will not overwrite existing files and returns an error instead.
>
> If a MyISAM table is created with a DATA DIRECTORY or INDEX DIRECTORY option and an existing .MYD or .MYI file is found, MyISAM always returns an error. It will not overwrite a file in the specified directory.

Comment: Thank you Tobias, for the fast answer to my question!
I removed the "index directory" option from the .sql file and the database was generated.

I hope this don't bring more problems :).

Thank you once again! _O_